# Make GitHub navigation pane always visible using local JS/CSS such as GreaseMonkey

Tags: script, html, github, greasemonkey

GitHub redesign of late made it much less usable since 2/3rd of screen real estate is no longer used:
[image: GitHub redesign with wasted space]

If you press on hamburger menu button, a useful sidebar appears, but it would disappear if you click anywhere outside it:
[image: GitHub with sidebar]

I would like to use some Chromium plugin to modify DOM/CSS tree of GitHub to make this sidebar displayed on all pages always, as shown on the GIMPed screenshot below:

[image]

I would be grateful for instructions to do so. I guess that repositioning it to a different place of DOM tree and making visible should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The left sidebar sort of doesn't load the data before clicking on the hamburger button, and I have no clue how the site works in general, but I made something a bit tacky.

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         GitHub - Left sidebar always visible
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      4
// @description  superuser.com/questions/1794556
// @match        https://github.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
  'use strict';

  const css = `

  @media only screen and (min-width: 1300px) {

    .application-main {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row-reverse !important;
      width: 100%;
    } .application-main deferred-side-panel > div {
      display: flex !important;
      position: sticky;
      padding-top: 1em;
    } .application-main modal-dialog {
      max-height: 96vh !important;
      display: flex !important;
    }

    .application-main > div[class=""],
    .application-main main {
      width: 100%;
    }

    .application-main .Overlay-backdrop--side {
      background-color: transparent;
      display: flex !important;
      z-index: 1;
    }

    .application-main > div > div > aside.team-left-column,
    .AppHeader-globalBar-start > deferred-side-panel,
    .application-main deferred-side-panel > button[id],
    .application-main deferred-side-panel > div[class] .Overlay-actionWrap {
      display: none !important;
    }

  }
  `;

  const styleElement = document.createElement('style');

  styleElement.textContent = css;

  document.head.appendChild(styleElement);

  var openButton = document.querySelector("deferred-side-panel > include-fragment > button[id]");
  var closeButton = document.querySelector(".Overlay-actionWrap > .close-button");

  function trigMenu() {

    setTimeout(function() {

      if (openButton === null) {
        openButton = document.querySelector("deferred-side-panel > include-fragment > button[id]");
        return;
      }

      if (openButton.isConnected) {
          openButton.click();
      } else {
          openButton = document.querySelector("deferred-side-panel > include-fragment > button[id]");
      }

      if (closeButton.isConnected) {
          closeButton.click();
      } else {
          closeButton = document.querySelector(".Overlay-actionWrap > .close-button");
      }

      setTimeout(function() {

        const main = document.querySelector(".application-main");

        const leftPanel = document.querySelector(".AppHeader-globalBar-start > deferred-side-panel");

        if (leftPanel) {
          main.appendChild(leftPanel);
        }

      }, 750);

    }, 1);

  }

  const observer = new MutationObserver(function(m) {
    for (const mutation of m) {
      if (mutation.target.tagName === 'DIV') {
        if (window.location.pathname.match(/\/(users|orgs)\/.*?\/projects\/.*/g)) { return }
        trigMenu();
      }
    }
  });

  observer.observe(document.body, { childList: true, subtree: true });

})();
```

All the code does is it injects CSS that makes the menu bar follow the screen view. Then whenever the DOM changes, it moves the rendered sidebar element to another node as it clicks the toggle menu button so the dynamic data will load.

Most of the work is done in CSS. I didn't explore every page for glaring element collisions, but so far it seems to be okay on the common pages. I'm also pretty sure there are better ways to handle/optimize this code.

Comment: Looks great so far - will do more testing this week

Comment: @alamar cool. i've realized the observer already makes sure the button gets clicked, so i removed the other functions and reduced the delay so the content would immediately be seen as the page finishes loading

Comment: Much better now! Thanks.

Comment: Is there a way to add some CSS so that the pane snaps to the upper border of viewport and when the page is scrolled, the pane floats and stays visible? It has the exact height to support that but currently doesn't.

Comment: that would likely require an intersection observer in JS, but it would be workable. an alternative would be to just use CSS to move the header navigation to the right and let the sidebar completely allocate the left side in a fixed manner

Comment: fortunately, the sidebar doesn't seem to break when moved into another node than what i first thought. well, hopefully it doesn't if there's any function in it that i don't know. the last edit should be able to make the sidebar snap to the screen

Comment: That's just great! Can you please also productionalize the @name tag so that one can copy-paste it and get a descriptive name of the script? The link is duplicated in description anyway